# How do I find files with a greater numerical value than a file based upon timestamp in the filename

Tags: bash, database-management

New to Linux and bash shell scripting so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I'm looking to find all files in a directory with a greater numerical filename than another filename uising a bash shell script.

The filename being used for comparison: Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-070001.csv

My Files :

```
 Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-094501.csv
 Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-093001.csv
 Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-091501.csv 
 Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-090001.csv 
 Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-070001.csv
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
 Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-094501.csv
 Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-093001.csv
 Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-091501.csv
 Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-090001.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
X='Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-070001.csv'
for n in `ls`; do   # run this in the folder with your files
  if [[ $n > $X ]]; then
    echo $n;
  fi;
done
```

Example:

```
> ls
Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-070001.csv  Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-091501.csv  Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-094501.csv
Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-090001.csv  Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-093001.csv

> ./../so1.sh 
Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-090001.csv
Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-091501.csv
Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-093001.csv
Jimmy_1_2019-05-11-094501.csv
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering. I tried this solution, but it echoed the first line of each file instead of comparing the filenames. My /tmp/d.txt is a directory not a file.

Comment: OK, updated to use a directory listing instead

Comment: Still no dice; the if statement isn't being applied to the output

Comment: are you sure you are using `bash`?

Comment: This code worked, I had the incorrect 'ls' command in the loop. I needed to refine the output.